# Vertx - missing GET parameters while securing route using OAuth2

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, vert.x

I followed this example of securing route using OAuth2 with GitHub provider: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_oauth2authhandler_handler and it works fine, except missing GET parameters after request redirection.

My code:

```
public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        OAuth2Auth authProviderGitHub = GithubAuth.create(vertx, "<CLIENT_ID>", "<CLIENT_SECRET>");

        OAuth2AuthHandler oauth2 = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(authProviderGitHub, "http://localhost:8080/callback"); 

        oauth2.setupCallback(router.route());

        router.route("/protected/*").handler(oauth2);

        Handler<RoutingContext> requestHandler = (routingContext) -> {
            String paramValue = routingContext.request().getParam("param");
            routingContext.response().end("PARAM: " + paramValue);
        };

        router.get("/endpoint").handler(requestHandler);
        router.get("/protected/endpoint").handler(requestHandler);

        server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
    }
}
```

I have two simple endpoints:

```
/endpoint     // public, without protection
```

and

```
/protected/endpoint // protected with OAuth2
```

When I call from a browser */endpoint* with

```
 http://localhost:8080/endpoint?param=foo
```

it works as expected and return **PARAM: foo**, whereas when I call protected endpoint with

```
http://localhost:8080/protected/endpoint?param=foo
```

it correctly redirect me to GitHub login page, then return query to my handler but without GET parameters, so response from the endpoint is **PARAM: null**.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On vert.x <= 3.4.2 only the path was being used for the redirect, the 3.5 series has been improved and can rely on the full uri, so your code will work on that version.

Comment: On 3.5.0.Beta1 still doesn't work. Do you know if change to POST and providing parameters in body will work with 3.4.2?

Comment: That is correct the fix was merged after beta1 current snapshot do work.